# Extract middle section of lines of a text file?

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing

I am writing a PHP script to parse a large text file to do database inserts from it. However on my host, the file is too large, and I hit the memory limit for PHP.

The file has about 16,000 lines; I want to split it up into four separate files (at first) to see if I can load those.

The first part I can get with `head -4000 file.txt`. The middle sections are slightly trickier -- I was thinking about piping `tail` output into `head` ( `tail -4001 file.txt | head -4000 > section2.txt` ), but is there another/better way?

Actually my logic is messed up -- for section two, I would need to so something like `tail -12001 file.txt | head - 4000`, and then lower the `tail` argument for the next sections. I'm getting mixed up already! :P

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want not to get messed up but still do it using `tail` and `head`, there is a useful way of invoking `tail` using a line-count from the beginning, not the end:

```
tail -n +4001 yourfile | head -4000
```

... But a better, automatic tool made just for splitting files is called... **`split`**! It's also a part of GNU coreutils, so any normal Linux system should have it. Here's how you can use it:

```
split -l 4000 yourInputFile thePrefixForOutputFiles
```

(See `man split` if in doubt.)

Comment: Given that `split` will split the file into three chunks, only one of which one cares about, surely the `sed` answer is preferable.

Answer (score 30):

Combining head and tail as you did will work, but for this I would use `sed`

```
sed -n '1,4000p' input_file # print lines 1-4000 of input_file
```

This lets you solve your problem with a quick shell function

```
chunk_it(){
    step=4
    start=1
    end=$step
    for n in {1..4} ; do
        sed -n "${start},${end}p" "$1" > "$1".$start-$end
        let start+=$step
        let end+=$step
    done
}

chunk_it your_file
```

Now you have your_file.1-4000 and yuor_file.4001-8000 and so on.

Note: requires bash

Comment: I like the sed way.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because sed doesn't exit. It prints out the lines I want to stdout, but I have to ctrl-c out, and as a result, I can't redirect it to a file. Any suggestion to make it usable?

Comment: Figured it out!
"sed -n '<start_line>,<end_line>w <output_file>' <input_file>"
works for me.

Comment: @Brent212 Another option to note is that you can also pipe it into less or redirect the output to a file.

Comment: On GNU `sed`, redirecting can work. The problem is that sed buffers its output by default. [Use `-u` to disable buffering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153217/65991) and redirecting should work. Note that the `-u` option is not available on all versions of `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) like

```bsh
bat -r 4001:8000 input-file.txt >output-file-1.txt
```

The benefit is that you can omit the output redirection to get an idea what’s being written:

[image: project specification for Bat]

Note: It’s probably overkill to install `bat` *just* for this feature; this answer is useful if you already have it installed for some reason.