# Cannot redirect output from sed

Tags: sed, io-redirection

I'm piping output from clock through sed to remove leading zeroes from numbers.
It looks like this:

```
clock -sf 'S%A, %B %d. %I:%M %P' | sed 's/\b0\+\([0-9]\+\)/\1/g'
```

That works fine and produces the output I want.

However, when I try to redirect the output to a file, nothing is written to the file. The following does NOT work.

```
clock -sf 'S%A, %B %d. %I:%M %P' | sed 's/\b0\+\([0-9]\+\)/\1/g' > testfile
```

Nothing is written to testfile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have the `clock` command on my Linux system, what does it do. Does it produce one line of output and exit, or does it produce continuous output?

Comment: With these flags it produces continuous output.

Comment: Running the second command without the sed pipe (redirecting clock directly into the file) works as expected. Running the second command without -s results in a single line being written to the file, as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running into an output buffering problem. `sed` normally buffers its output when not writing to a terminal, so nothing gets written to the file until the buffer fills up (probably every 4K bytes).

Use the `-u` option to `sed` to unbuffer output.

```
clock -sf 'S%A, %B %d. %I:%M %P' | sed -u 's/\b0\+\([0-9]\+\)/\1/g' > testfile
```

Comment: `-u` is a GNU specific option

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem while trying to redirect from a streaming output source.

You should use the `-u` (unbuffered) flag with sed and then PIPE the data instead of appending it with `>>` operator (`>>` locks the file and is blocking).

Instead doing the following works

```
someprogram | sed '/filter/' | tee myfile.txt
```

Comment: Sorry for taking 6 years to respond. I just checked the dates. Hope it will help someone who comes looking?