# Why I can't redirect output in some circumstances

Tags: pipe, io-redirection

for example

```
# this line should output ssh banner
nc localhost 22
# this line should output the same string expect the replacements
nc localhost 22|sed 's/SSH/XXX/g'

nc localhost 22 > foo # after killing the process, I can see the banner in file `foo`
nc localhost 22|sed 's/SSH/XXX/g' > foo # however I see nothing when sed is used
```

as mentioned, if I use `sed` to pipe the `nc`'s output, the `sed`'s output can't be redirected to a file.

And I also tried other commands to pipe the result, like `grep`, `tr`, the same result.

However, `cat` can pipe the result to a file. strange..

```
nc localhost 22|cat > foo
```

So why this happen? what is the difference between `cat` and other commands in this situation? how can I make `sed`'s output redirect to file like `cat` ?

Comment: Possibly buffering - try `sed -u` or `sed --unbuffered` if your system's implementation of `sed` supports it, or something like `stdbuf -oL sed 's/SSH/XXX/g'`

Comment: ... see related [Cannot redirect output from sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153210/cannot-redirect-output-from-sed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat | sed -e 's/foo/bar/' > output.txt 
foo
^C
$ cat output.txt 
[nothing]
```

but:

```
$ cat | sed -e 's/foo/bar/' > output.txt 
foo
^D
$ cat output.txt 
bar
```

Writes to files --but not to the terminal-- are usually buffered by the C library (the stdio functions) to blocks of some kilobytes.
If you hit Ctrl-C to kill the pipeline, `sed` won't have time to write out the buffers before it dies, so the resulting output file is empty. <sub>(You could say it's a bug in the C library that it doesn't catch the termination signal for that, but so it goes.)</sub>

Plain `cat` probably doesn't use stdio, since it doesn't deal with anything complicated like lines. Something like `cat -n` might be different, or not.

You could arrange so that you don't need to terminate the pipe with Ctrl-C, but have it complete by itself. At least in my `nc`, the `-qN` option tells it to exit after *N* seconds after stdin is closed, so e.g.:

```
$ printf '' | nc -q0 localhost 22 | sed 's/SSH/FOO/' > output.txt 
$ cat output.txt 
FOO-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7
```

Alternatively, there's at least a few ways to turn of buffering, see e.g.
[Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/170373) and
[`unbuffer` or `stdbuf` for removing stdout buffering?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97294/170373)

Also GNU sed has the `-u`/ `--unbuffered` switch to

> load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often