# Capture text between curly braces in C preprocessed file

Tags: bash, text-processing

I'm working with a preprocessed C source file. I want to extract one function for additional processing. I can find the start of the particular function with:

```
gcc -DNDEBUG -march=native -E source.c > source.pre

BEGIN=$(grep -n 'static inline int some_function' source.pre | cut -f 1 -d ':')
```

After the above executes, I have a line number where the function begins. In this case, its 7812.

I am having trouble devising a way to capture the text between the C function's curly braces (`{` and `}`). Based on [Extract middle section of lines of a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22623), I think this is reducing to a problem of finding the immediate closing brace (`}`).

How do find the immediate closing brace? Or how do I capture the text between curly braces in C preprocessed file?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming nothing wacky in the source that might place a stray `}` on a line by itself, try `sed`.

```
sed -n '/^static inline int some_function(/,/^}$/p' source.pre
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. That's much easier than the path I was going down.